# How can I read one message at a time from /var/mail

Tags: postfix, mutt, mailx

Lets say I have 5 messages in /var/mail/ and I want to read one message at a time and then do some string search in that mail before moving on to the next message. Is there a command that I can use to parse one message at a time ?

I am looking to write a bash script which will read all messages in an mbox file & then read them one at a time so that I can then extract Subject, To, From & Status of the message(bounceback code). My plan was to use grepmail to get count of emails in the file and then use this count in a for loop to get one mail at a time and them perform operation on the text. Something like:

```
$count = grepmail -r . /var/mail/user | awk '{print $2}'
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++) {
    $content = *GetMessage* -number $i /var/mail/user
    ...
    Do string operation on this message & save to $DelimitedData
    ...
}
$Delimiteddata
```

I can't figure out how to pickup single message at a time to perform string operation on them. Can someone please guide me which command/program can help me do this non interactively.

Comment: I'm guessing you mostly work with powershell?

Comment: @Jesse_b Yes I mostly script in powershell. I have a script that does exactly what I want, but we are moving to a linux box for some of the emails and I want to make sure that I get the reports.

Comment: You can install powershell on linux, but hopefully someone can also help you with a shell solution as it will be faster.

Comment: @Gilles `formail` answer is good, but it's also worth knowing that the "beginning of message" marker in an mbox format file is a line beginning with `From ` ("From" and a space character).  This can reliably be used to split mbox files into individual messages, with the regexp `^From ` as it is guaranteed NOT to be within the headers or body of the message (any body lines that would have started with "From " are changed when saved into an mbox, usually to ">From " or similar).    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`formail`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/procmail/formail.1.en.html) tool from [procmail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail) (available in any distribution, it's a classic) is designed precisely for this purpose.

Basic usage:

```
formail -s myprogram --option
```

runs `myprogram --option` on each mail in turn. The program receives each mail on its standard input.

Comment: Not sure that `formail` can pick up the Nth message in an existing spool file, though  Can it?

Comment: @roaima I don't think it's needed (the OP had that loop because they didn't know how to process messages in an mbox one-by-one), but `formail` has a `+skip` option, and a `-total` option (the "skip" in the `+skip` is the number of messages to skip, and the "total" in `-total` is the total number of msgs to output - so `+5 -1` would output only the 6th message).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Gilles. I can't figure out how to use the stream from formail in a shell script. In my test script I am just reading input from formail -s command & displaying it but i don't get any output & the script waits until I press Ctrl+C. Here's my script:
#!/bin/sh
print $1
read -p message </dev/tty
echo "${message}"

I am calling it by  formail -s test.sh -d

Comment: @OjasP `formail` reads from standard input, so e.g. `formail </var/mail/bob -s test.sh`

Comment: Thanks @Gilles! For someone else who stumbles across this, I used this command: `formail -s </var/mail/user ./test.sh` . And, in the test.sh file I am reading the message using `message=$(</dev/stdin)`